# cannot load such file -- /home/sandhya/robly/spec/factories (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm using Factory_girl_rails in my new project which is in rails 3.2.8. I'm getting the  above error.
Can anyone please suggest me what to do.

```
/home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/sandhya/robly/spec/factories (LoadError)
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/sandhya/robly/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/sandhya/robly/spec/models/address_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/sandhya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@robly/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

My gemfile goes like this:

group :

```
test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "capybara"
end
```

and in my factories.rb I have

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do |v|
    v.email "test@email.com"
    v.state "Karnataka"
    v.country "India"
    v.zip_code "560061"
    v.office_mobiel "9999999999"
    v.company "Some Company"
    v.city "Bangalore"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, FactoryGirl should load factories.rb by itself. But did you include FactoryGirl in your spec_helper.rb file?

If yes, more infos would be necessary, at least the contents of the two files mentioned in your stacktrace: /spec/spec_helper.rb and /spec/models/address_spec.rb

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too when I upgrade factory_girl from 3.5.0 to 4.1.0.
I used to write "require 'factories'" on 3.5.0 and no error occurred.
Maybe you do not need "require 'factories'" on 4.1.0